# Не загружаются файлы на сервер через скрипт

Tags: php

Пытаюсь использовать готовый php скрипт для загрузки аватарок на сервер.

**upload.php**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Результат загрузки файла</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*3*1024)
   {
     echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
     exit;
   }
   // Проверяем загружен ли файл
   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
   {
     // Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
     // из временной директории в конечную
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "/s92640jz.bget.ru/public_html/API/avatars/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
   } else {
      echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**123.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Загрузка файлов на сервер</title>
</head>
<body>
      <h2><p><b> Форма для загрузки файлов </b></p></h2>
      <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="filename"><br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Загрузить"><br>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Папка куда я делаю загрузку находится в /s92640jz.bget.ru/public_html/API/avatars/

Права у этой папки и у скрипта upload.php 777

При загрузке файлов просто белый экран, без сообщений об ошибке.
[Тут лежит сам скрипт, если кому интересно](http://s92640jz.bget.ru/API/123.html)

Comment: Посмотри лог PHP возможно там ошибка.

Comment: [28-Sep-2016 10:40:57 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/s92640jz.bget.ru/public_html/API/avatars/f48e6645.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/s/s92640jz/s92640jz.bget.ru/public_html/API/upload.php on line 17
[28-Sep-2016 10:40:57 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpBjTTAL' to '/s92640jz.bget.ru/public_html/API/avatars/f48e6645.jpg' in /home/s/s92640jz/s92640jz.bget.ru/public_html/API/upload.php on line 17

Comment: Путь назначения указан не верно .